# What's meaning of (size_t)(uint32_t)-(int32_t)(nTableMask)

Tags: php, c, casting, type-conversion

PHP is written by C,when i read the source code ,I found a stranger Macro expansion,which like below.

`(size_t)(uint32_t)-(int32_t)(nTableMask)  // nTableMask=-8`

I use **gdb** to print `(size_t)(uint32_t)`,it is wrong

`` (gdb) p (size_t)(uint32_t)
A syntax error in expression, near `'. ``

but when i change the expression,it work

`(gdb) p (size_t)(uint32_t)-(int32_t)(-8)
$21 = 8`

## My problem:

what's meaning of  `(size_t)(uint32_t)-(int32_t)(-8)`?
I know `(size_t)(uint32_t)` is wrong ,but why `(size_t)(uint32_t)-(int32_t)(-8)` is a right expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(size_t)(uint32_t)-(int32_t)(-8)
```

is first     `(int32_t)(-8)` or `0xFFFFFFF8`

then it's    `(uint32_t)- -8` or `(uint32_t)8` or `0x00000008`

finally it's `(size_t) 8` as `size_t` may be a different size than `uint32_t`

it will be `0x0000000000000008` on a 64bit system.

Answer (score 1):

Code: `(size_t)(uint32_t)-(int32_t)(nTableMask)`
It means:

```
1. -(int32_t)(nTableMask) //Cast nTableMask to signed int32 and invert sign
2. (uint32_t) //cast value on step 1 to unsigned int32
3. (size_t) //cast value on step 2 to unsigned int64
```

This code is using to calculate size of hashtable part of arData (upper part).

/*

```
 * HashTable Data Layout
 * =====================
 *
 *                 +=============================+
 *                 | HT_HASH(ht, ht->nTableMask) |
 *                 | ...                         |
 *                 | HT_HASH(ht, -1)             |
 *                 +-----------------------------+
 * ht->arData ---> | Bucket[0]                   |
 *                 | ...                         |
 *                 | Bucket[ht->nTableSize-1]    |
 *                 +=============================+
 */
```